# Make a single-line comment in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

How can I make PhpStorm with a short PHPDoc comments show the comment in a single line instead of multiple lines?

How that is displayed now:

```
/**
 * @return int[]
 */
public static function defaultAccountValidationCollection(){}
```

I want this:

```
/** @return int[] */
public static function defaultAccountValidationCollection(){}
```

Comment: Why not `//comment` ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Because `//comment` is NOT PHPDoc comment

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't know, this maybe can help OP [link](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2646)

Comment: @Mohsen So you want to generate single-line comment .. or to display it in a more compact way? **To display:** well, you can collapse it (auto-folding is also available). Otherwise I do not see how a comment with `@param` or other lines would need to be displayed here. **To generate:** how it supposed to look when you will have `@param` there? Anyway: `Settings | File & Code Templates` -- you can adjust some stuff there,

Comment: This is about coding style, I recommend reading more about https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#5-the-phpdoc-format and when you start using a linter you will get warnings for /** @return int[] */. If someone else is asking you to do this make sure they read it too.

Comment: I'm assuming typing out ```/** ``` and then pressing space is not what you want?

Comment: @LazyOne
My intention was if I have a small function that doesn't use a param and only returns something, I want the comment to be made in a single line instead of multipal line.

Comment: @Tropus 
Then I have to type what the function returns. but I want to make PHP Strom do that automatically

Comment: @Mohsen So what are you going to do if a function has parameter or two? Use different formatting style? If that's so -- bad approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change Function Doc Comment Template for PhpStorm like this:

`/** ${PARAM_DOC} #if (${TYPE_HINT} != "void") @return ${TYPE_HINT} #end ${THROWS_DOC} */`

[image: *]

But single line doc approach is not useful. Because; functions can take multiple parameters, can return different objects, can have proper explanation of what it does. Why do you limit yourself?

You can use single line doc for variables and properties. Write above them: `/**` and press `space`.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use:

[PhpStrom - Editor - File and Code Templates - Includes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DCMK.png)

```
#if (${PARAM_DOC} == "") && (${THROWS_DOC} == "")
    /*** @return ${TYPE_HINT} */
#else
/**
${PARAM_DOC}
#if (${TYPE_HINT} != "void") * @return ${TYPE_HINT} #end
${THROWS_DOC}
*/
#end
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it, and please avoid using images as the sole content of your answer